# How do I install the same pip dependencies locally as are installed in my Cloud Composer Airflow environment on GCP?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, pip, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I'm trying to set up a local development environment in VS Code where I'd get code completion for the packages Cloud Composer/Apache Airflow uses. I've been successful so far using a virtual environment (created with `python -m venv .venv`) and a very minimal `requirements.txt` file that contains just the Airflow package, installed into the local environment.

The file is like this:

```
apache-airflow==1.10.15
```

And I can install it into my virtual environment by running `pip install -r requirements.txt` after activating my virtual environment in VS Code, after which I get code completion in VS Code for the quickstart DAG in their docs, the `BashOperator`:

[image]

I wanted to get more code completion as I followed more tutorials. For example, following the `KubernetesPodOperator` tutorial (https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/using-kubernetes-pod-operator), I get this error, and VS Code doesn't recognize the import:

```
Import "airflow.providers.cncf.kubernetes.operators.kubernetes_pod" could not be resolved Pylance(reportMissingImports)
```

I figured that a good next step would be to install exactly the same PyPI packages into my virtual environment as are running in the Cloud Composer environment. I used the page https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/versioning/composer-versions to see which packages were installed:

[image: versions in GCP UI]

So my `requirements.txt` file then looked like this:

```
absl-py==1.0.0
alembic==1.5.7
amqp==2.6.1
apache-airflow==1.10.15+composer
apache-airflow-backport-providers-apache-beam==2021.3.13
apache-airflow-backport-providers-cncf-kubernetes==2021.3.3
apache-airflow-backport-providers-google==2022.4.1+composer
apache-beam==2.37.0
apispec==1.3.3
appdirs==1.4.4
argcomplete==1.12.2
astunparse==1.6.3
attrs==20.3.0
Babel==2.9.0
bcrypt==3.2.0
billiard==3.6.3.0
cached-property==1.5.2
cachetools==4.2.1
cattrs==1.1.2
celery==4.4.7
certifi==2020.12.5
cffi==1.14.5
chardet==4.0.0
click==6.7
cloudpickle==2.0.0
colorama==0.4.4
colorlog==4.0.2
configparser==3.5.3
crcmod==1.7
croniter==0.3.37
cryptography==3.4.6
defusedxml==0.7.1
dill==0.3.1.1
distlib==0.3.1
dnspython==2.1.0
docopt==0.6.2
docutils==0.16
email-validator==1.1.2
fastavro==1.3.4
fasteners==0.17.3
filelock==3.0.12
Flask==1.1.2
Flask-Admin==1.5.4
Flask-AppBuilder==2.3.4
Flask-Babel==1.0.0
Flask-Bcrypt==0.7.1
Flask-Caching==1.3.3
Flask-JWT-Extended==3.25.1
Flask-Login==0.4.1
Flask-OpenID==1.3.0
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.5.1
flask-swagger==0.2.14
Flask-WTF==0.14.3
flower==0.9.7
funcsigs==1.0.2
future==0.18.2
gast==0.3.3
google-ads==7.0.0
google-api-core==1.31.5
google-api-python-client==1.12.8
google-apitools==0.5.31
google-auth==1.28.0
google-auth-httplib2==0.1.0
google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.3
google-cloud-aiplatform==1.12.1
google-cloud-automl==2.7.2
google-cloud-bigquery==1.28.0
google-cloud-bigquery-datatransfer==3.6.1
google-cloud-bigquery-storage==2.6.3
google-cloud-bigtable==1.7.0
google-cloud-build==2.0.0
google-cloud-container==1.0.1
google-cloud-core==1.6.0
google-cloud-datacatalog==3.7.1
google-cloud-dataplex==0.2.1
google-cloud-dataproc==3.3.1
google-cloud-dataproc-metastore==1.5.0
google-cloud-datastore==1.15.3
google-cloud-dlp==1.0.0
google-cloud-kms==2.11.1
google-cloud-language==1.3.0
google-cloud-logging==2.2.0
google-cloud-memcache==1.3.1
google-cloud-monitoring==2.0.0
google-cloud-os-login==2.6.1
google-cloud-pubsub==2.12.0
google-cloud-pubsublite==1.4.1
google-cloud-redis==2.8.0
google-cloud-resource-manager==1.4.1
google-cloud-secret-manager==1.0.0
google-cloud-spanner==1.19.1
google-cloud-speech==1.3.2
google-cloud-storage==1.36.2
google-cloud-tasks==2.8.1
google-cloud-texttospeech==1.0.1
google-cloud-translate==1.7.0
google-cloud-videointelligence==1.16.1
google-cloud-vision==1.0.0
google-cloud-workflows==1.6.1
google-crc32c==1.1.2
google-pasta==0.2.0
google-resumable-media==1.2.0
googleapis-common-protos==1.53.0
graphviz==0.16
grpc-google-iam-v1==0.12.3
grpcio==1.44.0
grpcio-gcp==0.2.2
grpcio-status==1.44.0
gunicorn==20.0.4
h5py==2.10.0
hdfs==2.6.0
httplib2==0.17.4
humanize==3.3.0
idna==2.8
importlib-metadata==2.1.1
importlib-resources==1.5.0
iso8601==0.1.14
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.3
json-merge-patch==0.2
jsonschema==3.2.0
Keras-Preprocessing==1.1.2
kombu==4.6.11
kubernetes==11.0.0
lazy-object-proxy==1.4.3
libcst==0.3.17
lockfile==0.12.2
Mako==1.1.4
Markdown==2.6.11
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
marshmallow==2.21.0
marshmallow-enum==1.5.1
marshmallow-sqlalchemy==0.23.1
mock==2.0.0
monotonic==1.5
mypy-extensions==0.4.3
mysqlclient==1.3.14
natsort==7.1.1
numpy==1.19.5
oauth2client==4.1.3
oauthlib==3.1.0
opt-einsum==3.3.0
orjson==3.6.8
overrides==6.1.0
packaging==20.9
pandas==1.1.5
pandas-gbq==0.14.1
pbr==5.8.1
pendulum==1.4.4
pip==20.1.1
pipdeptree==1.0.0
prison==0.1.3
prometheus-client==0.8.0
proto-plus==1.18.1
protobuf==3.15.6
psutil==5.8.0
psycopg2-binary==2.8.6
pyarrow==2.0.0
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
pycparser==2.20
pydata-google-auth==1.1.0
pydot==1.4.2
Pygments==2.8.1
PyJWT==1.7.1
pymongo==3.11.3
pyOpenSSL==20.0.1
pyparsing==2.4.7
pyrsistent==0.17.3
python-daemon==2.3.0
python-dateutil==2.8.1
python-editor==1.0.4
python-http-client==3.3.4
python-nvd3==0.15.0
python-slugify==4.0.1
python3-openid==3.2.0
pytz==2021.1
pytzdata==2020.1
PyYAML==5.4.1
redis==3.5.3
requests==2.25.1
requests-oauthlib==1.3.0
rsa==4.7.2
scipy==1.4.1
sendgrid==5.6.0
setproctitle==1.2.2
setuptools==57.5.0
six==1.15.0
SQLAlchemy==1.3.20
SQLAlchemy-JSONField==0.9.0
SQLAlchemy-Utils==0.36.8
statsd==3.3.0
tabulate==0.8.9
tenacity==4.12.0
tensorboard==2.2.2
tensorboard-plugin-wit==1.8.1
tensorflow==2.2.0
tensorflow-estimator==2.2.0
termcolor==1.1.0
text-unidecode==1.3
thrift==0.13.0
tornado==5.1.1
typing-extensions==3.7.4.3
typing-inspect==0.6.0
typing-utils==0.1.0
tzlocal==1.5.1
unicodecsv==0.14.1
uritemplate==3.0.1
urllib3==1.26.4
vine==1.3.0
virtualenv==20.4.3
websocket-client==0.58.0
Werkzeug==0.16.1
wheel==0.37.1
wrapt==1.12.1
WTForms==2.3.3
zipp==3.4.1
zope.deprecation==4.4.0
```

When I tried running `pip install -r requirements.txt` again, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement apache-airflow==1.10.15+composer (from versions: 1.10.9-bin, 1.8.1, 1.8.2rc1, 1.8.2, 1.9.0, 1.10.0, 1.10.1b1, 1.10.1rc2, 1.10.1, 1.10.2b2, 1.10.2rc1, 1.10.2rc2, 1.10.2rc3, 1.10.2, 1.10.3b1, 1.10.3b2, 1.10.3rc1, 1.10.3rc2, 1.10.3, 1.10.4b2, 1.10.4rc1, 1.10.4rc2, 1.10.4rc3, 1.10.4rc4, 1.10.4rc5, 1.10.4, 1.10.5rc1, 1.10.5, 1.10.6rc1, 1.10.6rc2, 1.10.6, 1.10.7rc1, 1.10.7rc2, 1.10.7rc3, 1.10.7, 1.10.8rc1, 1.10.8, 1.10.9rc1, 1.10.9, 1.10.10rc1, 1.10.10rc2, 1.10.10rc3, 1.10.10rc4, 1.10.10rc5, 1.10.10, 1.10.11rc1, 1.10.11rc2, 1.10.11, 1.10.12rc1, 1.10.12rc2, 1.10.12rc3, 1.10.12rc4, 1.10.12, 1.10.13rc1, 1.10.13, 1.10.14rc1, 1.10.14rc2, 1.10.14rc3, 1.10.14rc4, 1.10.14, 1.10.15rc1, 1.10.15, 2.0.0b1, 2.0.0b2, 2.0.0b3, 2.0.0rc1, 2.0.0rc2, 2.0.0rc3, 2.0.0, 2.0.1rc1, 2.0.1rc2, 2.0.1, 2.0.2rc1, 2.0.2, 2.1.0rc1, 2.1.0rc2, 2.1.0, 2.1.1rc1, 2.1.1, 2.1.2rc1, 2.1.2, 2.1.3rc1, 2.1.3, 2.1.4rc1, 2.1.4rc2, 2.1.4, 2.2.0b1, 2.2.0b2, 2.2.0rc1, 2.2.0, 2.2.1rc1, 2.2.1rc2, 2.2.1, 2.2.2rc1, 2.2.2rc2, 2.2.2, 2.2.3rc1, 2.2.3rc2, 2.2.3, 2.2.4rc1, 2.2.4, 2.2.5rc1, 2.2.5rc2, 2.2.5rc3, 2.2.5, 2.3.0b1, 2.3.0rc1, 2.3.0rc2, 2.3.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for apache-airflow==1.10.15+composer
```

When I looked at the PyPI website, I noticed that some of the packages that have "+composer" in their name in `requirements.txt` don't exist in PyPI. For example, `apache-airflow==1.10.15+composer` and `apache-airflow-backport-providers-google==2022.4.1+composer` don't exist there. Does this mean that those packages are not publicly available? I'm relatively new to Python and Airflow, so these are just some ideas I've been thinking of since I encountered this issue. I may be on the wrong track.

I'd appreciate any help I can get here in installing these packages into my local virtual environment, or installing some other packages that would achieve my goal of being able to do local development, with code completion, on DAGs.

Here's the script I used to create my environment for this test, for reference:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

gcloud composer environments create my-environment \
    --location us-central1 \
    --image-version composer-1.18.8-airflow-1.10.15 # uses Python 3.8.12
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So the two incompatibilities in Cloud Composer dependencies [as listed on the official website](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/versioning/composer-versions) are `apache-airflow` and `apache-airflow-providers-google` (or `apache-airflow-backport-providers-google` if you are using Cloud Composer v1).

---

What you need to do is to replace these two dependencies with the correct pins.

For example, if you are running `composer-2.0.16-airflow-2.2.5` version that specifies the two dependencies as

```
apache-airflow==2.2.5+composer
apache-airflow-providers-google==2022.5.18+composer
```

You need to replace them with

```
apache-airflow==2.2.5
apache-airflow-providers-google==7.0.0
```

---

If you are wondering how I came up with the  specific version for `apache-airflow-providers-google` then what you need to do is head the [page containing the list of commits included in each release](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/commits.html).

At the top of each release, you can see the date of the latest commit. Then the specific package version will be the one with the latest 'Latest change' prior to the date specified in the original listing on Cloud Composer version page (in this example that'd be `2022.5.18`).

[image]

---

Note that for some specific composer versions, the `apache-ariflow-providers-google` dependency is specified explicitly (.e.g `6.7.0` or `6.8.0`). Not sure if the date convention is there by mistake or perhaps a convention that we are not aware of (?)